# Flutter Quill can't deal withe more than one field?

Tags: flutter, dart, textfield, quill

I am using the latest version of [flutter quill](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_quill) in my flutter app. . In my use case, I have two fields in one screen which means two QuillEditor.basic widgets but  whatever I type in the first one automatically appears in the second one . I know it's a matter of controllers but I can't find a property in the QuillEditor.basic that refers to controller except for scrollController.

Here is my code. Intialized QuillController

```
  final quillController = QuillController.basic();
```

Used it in QuillProvider

```
body: QuillProvider(
           configurations: QuillConfigurations(controller: quillController),
```

Then my QuillEditor.basic which is a TextField and as you can see there is only scrollController property.

```
                                    scrollController: sentenceScrollController,
                                    configurations:
                                        const QuillEditorConfigurations(
                                      readOnly: false,
                                    ),
                                  ),
```

Is there any way to make this work or flutter quill is only built to deal with one single QuillEditor (text field)?